# How do I change the background color of v-btn on click inside v-bottom-nav

Tags: vuetify.js

I want to change the background color of a v-btn to black while the button is clicked inside a v-bottom-nav.

I have already tried but it's not working

```
<v-btn
    :color="changeBackgroundColor ? 'secondary' : 'info'"
    @click="changeBackgroundColor = !changeBackgroundColor"
>
```

I have the code in https://codepen.io/boidurja-talukdar/pen/ZddywR?editors=1010

I expect the background color of button 'A' to toggle from blue to black on click. But the actual result is that the text on button 'A' just disappears on click.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with style binding ... check this fork [codepen](https://codepen.io/Dadboz/pen/orrGPd?editors=1010)

```
   <v-btn
       @click="changeBackgroundColor = !changeBackgroundColor"
       :style="{
           backgroundColor : changeBackgroundColor ? 'black !important' : '',
           color: changeBackgroundColor ? 'white !important' : 'black'
           }"
   >
```

Comment: Thanks again for the answer.